# Specify which Javascript engineReactJS .NET uses

Tags: reactjs, reactjs.net

So, I know it's possible to specify a specific javascript engine with react for server side rendering. I just can't seem to find any info on it. Here's a blurb from one of their Github issues that confirms that it's possible:

> Have you tried running it with the V8 engine instead? The MS one can be flakey (we had similar issues with it but much early on in our dev cycle). The fact it works on 3 other enviros means there has to be a difference between those and the 4th one. Could be its got a different version IE on the production server for instance? Tricky one to track down hence switching to V8 might be a quicker option.

https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/188

Anyone know how to do this? I'm seeing inconsistencies between different machines and I think (like, 90%) the cause is different JS engines being used. I'd like to lock it down so only v8 gets used so things are consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.SetAllowMsieEngine(false)` on your ReactJS.NET configuration. For ASP.NET 4, that's in `App_Start\ReactConfig.cs` by default. For ASP.NET Core, it's in the `UseReact` call in `Startup.cs`.

This will force it to use V8, or throw an exception if it fails to load V8 (rather than falling back to MSIE). The most common issues is the `ClearScript.V8` directory missing from `bin`. This should be automatically copied across for ASP.NET 4 sites, but for ASP.NET Core you need to manually modify your build to do it (see http://reactjs.net/2016/08/protected-memory-exceptions-and-dotnet-core.html)

Comment: So, my project had ClearScript.dll, but not ClearScript.V8.dll added. When you say ClearScript.V8 directory.....do you mean dll? Or do I actually need to create a directory called ClearScript.V8 in the bin folder. And if THAT's the case, which of the ClearScript dlls do I need?

Thanks for the help, sorry for 20 questions :P

Comment: @NickPendleton Are you using ASP.NET 4 or ASP.NET Core? For ASP.NET 4, installing the JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8 NuGet package should configure everything correctly (Installing ReactJS.NET should automatically install this package too). For ASP.NET Core, you'll need to follow the steps in the blog post I linked to. There's actually four files in a ClearScript.V8 directory: ClearScriptV8-64.dll, v8-x64.dll, and 32-bit versions too.

Comment: ASP.NET 4. I do have JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8 added to the project. I think because of an oddity of my project structure, it's not getting configured properly. If I manually copy over the dlls, ReactEnvironment suddenly stops resolving. Working through the inner exceptions now.